# Gravity forms plugin - dynamically populating form field isn't working

Tags: forms, wordpress, gravity

I'm having some problems with my Gravity Forms form. It's a multi page form, and I need to populate a field on page 2 using post values from page 1. But it's not working. Of course the field on page 2 is configured to "Allow field to be populated dynamically" and the field's parameter is set to "name".
Here's my code:

```php
add_filter('gform_field_value_name', 'name_population_function');
function name_population_function($value){
    $name = $_POST['input_2'] . ' ' . ( ! empty( $_POST['input_3'] ) ? ( $_POST['input_3'] . ' ' ) : NULL ) . $_POST['input_1'];
    return $name;
}
```

When I print the value of `$name` variable using `var_dump($name);` it's actually correct.

If I change the `$name` to `$name = 'Last Middle First';` it's populating the field as it should.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
For test purposes I changed my code to:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_name', 'name_population_function');
function name_population_function($value){
    $name = 'Test';
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['input_1'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['input_2'] ) ) {
        $name = $_POST['input_2'] . ' ' . ( ! empty( $_POST['input_3'] ) ? ( $_POST['input_3'] . ' ' ) : NULL ) . $_POST['input_1'];
    //var_dump( $name );
    }
    return $name;
}
```

If I uncomment the line with `var_dump` the value of variable `$name` is again set correctly, but the field on page 2 is prepopulated with value `Test`. Probably this filter is also called on page 1 so is it possible that the plugin caches this value? I don't use a caching plugin, so don't know why it's not working.

Comment: When you var dump, are you doing it on the second page, or on the first page?

Comment: The var_dump was placed in name_population_function in function.php file right before the `return` and the first page was already sent.

Comment: Sorry for posting late but in case someone else has this problem I found that using AJAX posting does not actually post content from page to page but just shows/hides parts of the form to give the appearance of pages. Disabling AJAX posting allowed me to populate fields from one page to a later page. If you really need AJAX posting enabled then you may need to use the JavaScript hooks to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having the form over multiple pages, you could use jQuery to create the impression of multiple pages with `.hide` or `.slideToggle`. This would resolve your problem and make the submitting of the form data much easier. Then simply call the value from past inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query string to persist the data and populate the field dynamically.

http://siteurl.com/form-url/?your_parameter=value

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_author_email', 'populate_post_author_email');
function populate_post_author_email($value){
global $post;

$author_email = get_the_author_meta('email', $post->post_author);

return $author_email;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this gform_pre_render filter instead. It adds a filter to form ID 7. Replace 7 with your Gravity form's ID.

```
add_filter('gform_pre_render_7', 'populate_form_pre_render');

function populate_form_pre_render($form){
  $name ='';
  foreach ($form['fields'] as &$field)
  {
     // replace 2 with the actual ID of your form field 
    if ( 2 == $field['id'] ){
      if ( ! empty( $_POST['input_1'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['input_2'] ) ) {
         $name = $_POST['input_2'] . ' ' . ( ! empty( $_POST['input_3'] ) ? ($_POST['input_3'] . ' ' ) : NULL ) . $_POST['input_1'];
        //var_dump( $name );
      }
      $field['defaultValue']=$name;
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($field);
  echo '</pre>';
   }    

 }

 return $form;
}
```

Comment: Why in  foreach ($form['fields'] as &$field) are you passing $field by reference? I'm just wondering why do it?

Comment: Because you're changing the value of the field and then at the end of the function you're returning the modified $form object. If you passed by value your changes would be lost.